# child object initialised to parent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, casting

B is a subclass of class A.

```
A * a = [[B alloc] init];
B * b = [[A alloc] init];
```

Which of these is invalid and why?

When I typed this in I got a warning for the second thing, but I couldn't understand what it meant. It showed "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'B * __strong' with an expression of type 'A *'". Also may some one tell me if the second expression can be made valid or not and how to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `B` is a *subclass* of `A`, its instances may be used everywhere where instances of `A` could be used. The inverse is not true.

Here is a real-life example using Apple's classes: consider `NSArray` and its subclass `NSMutableArray`. Since `NSMutableArray` *is an* `NSArray`, the following assignment is valid:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

However, since `NSArray` is not necessarily an `NSMutableArray`, the following assignment is invalid:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

**EDIT** From the language point of view, both assignments are valid: the code is going to compile, and may even run if you steer clear of `B`'s methods not also supported by `A`, thanks to the dynamic method dispatch mechanism of Objective C. But the compiler can no longer validate the code that involves the variable, and tell you of other potential problems.

Comment: So to be explicit: The second example, where an instance of A is being used in a place that is declared as B, is invalid.

Comment: So which one is valid? and then why the warning?

Comment: So the second one is invalid. That much is clear. But a proper reason why is still unclear.

Comment: @ShyamK This is a warning, not an error, because assigning an incompatible pointer is not in itself incorrect. It usually *is* incorrect, but the language does not prohibit it, and it may even run without causing any trouble. For example, if I assign an `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` pointer but then use only the methods supported by both `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`, my program would run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
A * a = [[B alloc] init];  // OK
B * b = [[A alloc] init];  // INCORRECT
```

Simply put, the first line is valid because any instance of B is necessarily an instance of A. It's therefore fine to assign a pointer to an instance of B to a variable of type `A*`.

The second line is incorrect for a similar reason: instances of A are not necessarily instances of B, so it's not fine to assign a pointer to an instance of A to a variable of type `B*`. More specifically, in the second line you're instantiating A directly, so the resulting object is definitely *not* an instance of B.

Think of it this way: it's correct to describe any square as a rectangle, but it's incorrect to say without extra information that a rectangle is a square.